# Failed to create ipa for Adhoc through Codemagic

Tags: ios, native, codemagic

I am trying to generate the ipa through Codemagic, but it's pass all the script and failed to generate ipa

```
workflows:
  prod-adhoc:
    name: Production Build - AdHoc Distribution
    environment:
      vars:
        XCODE_WORKSPACE: "project.xcworkspace"
        XCODE_SCHEME: "project"
        BUNDLE_ID: "com.project.app"
        APP_STORE_CONNECT_ISSUER_ID: Encrypted()
        APP_STORE_CONNECT_KEY_IDENTIFIER: Encrypted()
        APP_STORE_CONNECT_PRIVATE_KEY: Encrypted()
        CERTIFICATE_PRIVATE_KEY: Encrypted()
      xcode: latest
      cocoapods: default
    scripts:
      - find . -name "Podfile" -execdir pod install \;
      - name: Set up keychain to be used for codesigning using Codemagic CLI 'keychain' command
        script: keychain initialize
      - name: Fetch signing files
        script: # You can allow creating resources if existing are not found with `--create` flag
            app-store-connect fetch-signing-files $BUNDLE_ID --type IOS_APP_ADHOC --create
      - name: Set up signing certificate
        script:
          xcode-project use-profiles
      - name: Increment build number
        script: agvtool new-version -all $BUILD_NUMBER
      - name: Build ipa for Adhoc
        script: xcode-project build-ipa --workspace "$XCODE_WORKSPACE" --scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME" --verbose
    artifacts:
      - build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
      - /tmp/xcodebuild_logs/*.log
      - $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**/Build/**/*.dSYM
    publishing:
      email:
        recipients:
          - neha@gmail.com
```

❌  error:  No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found: No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "XXXXX" with a private key was found. (in target 'project' from project 'project')

❌  error: No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found: No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "xxxxxx" with a private key was found. (in target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' from project 'project')

I had checked with project setting it's on Automatic

Answer (score 0):

Try to add one more script after `Fetch signing files` to tell VM to use certificate:

```
- name: Use system default keychain
    script: keychain add-certificates
```

Comment: error: project has conflicting provisioning settings. project is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "Apple Development" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Project' from project 'Project')

Answer (score 0):

check the output from `xcode-project use-profiles` command. It has detailed information about code signing settings, I'm wondering why error message says about Distribution certificate